# float only one part in a section/div

Tags: css, html

I have a section in html page whose max width is set by a container. The heading and two columns in the section aren't floated. only the columns are floated left while the heading is center text aligned. Because of this the border that I put for the section wraps around the heading. Because of this some sections of page after this is being mis aligned. Is there a way I can fix it?

```
<section class="carousel freedom container"> <!--Freedom section -->

 <h1> This is the heading </h1> 

<ul class="two-col left-col">
<li class="pen"> <span class="icon-text"> <span> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</span> </li>
<li class="phone"> <span class="icon-text"> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</span> </li>
</ul>
<ul class="two-col right-col">
<li class="arrow"> <span class="icon-text"> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</span> </li>
<li class="download"> <span class="icon-text"> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT </li>
</ul>
 </section>   <!--End of Freedom carousel -->
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/7khffLsm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7khffLsm/2/)

You could use `display: inline-block;` to `.left-col, .right-col` and remove `float: left;`

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    max-width:1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.left-col, .right-col {
    list-style: none;
    width: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.two-col li {
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 30%;
}
.carousel h1 {
    font-family:"HelveticaNeueMedium", "HelveticaNeue-Medium", "Helvetica Neue Medium", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica";
    font-size: 20pt;
    color: #252525;
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 24pt;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
}
.carousel.freedom {
    border: 2px solid;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<section class="carousel freedom container">
    <!--Freedom section -->
     <h1> This is the heading </h1> 
    <ul class="two-col left-col">
        <li class="pen"> <span class="icon-text"> <span> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</span> 
        </li>
        <li class="phone"> <span class="icon-text"> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</span> 
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="two-col right-col">
        <li class="arrow"> <span class="icon-text"> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</span> 
        </li>
        <li class="download"> <span class="icon-text"> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT </li>
</ul>
</section>   <!--End of Freedom carousel -->
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! But, there was a slight misalignment of the text in 1st column. Its pushed further down than the second column. I am not sure why though.

Comment: JSFiddle Show - http://jsfiddle.net/7khffLsm/2/show/ and [Image](http://oi61.tinypic.com/f1e05d.jpg)

Comment: I should have mentione dthis earlier. My apologies. It works fine in fiddle. When I integrate with my code it gets mis aligned.

Comment: It seems there was some sort of influence from other css settings. I redid the section again instead of copy paste and it worked. Thanks.